# (Python3)Tic-tac-toe: IndexError: tuple index out of range

Tags: indexing, tuples

**Hello, I've been programming for 3 weeks and this is my first milestone project.**

I was trying out a template for an interactive tic-tac-toe game. What I want to do is format the empty board with X's and O's from a list that is filled by user input.

```
emptyboard = """
    {1} | {2} | {3}
    ____|_____|____
    {4} | {5} | {6}
    ____|_____|____
    {7} | {8} | {9}
        |     |"""
print(emptyboard)
print(emptyboard.format(["#","X","O","O","O","O","X","X","X","X"]))
```

And I get an IndexError, yet I think that I have enough values in both my table and string formatting method. Output:

```
    {1} | {2} | {3}
    ____|_____|____
    {4} | {5} | {6}
    ____|_____|____
    {7} | {8} | {9}
        |     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-4c3674aa4a8b> in <module>
      7         |     |"""
      8 print(emptyboard)
----> 9 print(emptyboard.format(["#","X","O","O","O","O","X","X","X","X"]))

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Thanks in advance to everyone who tries to help! I will look up other ways of coding the game, but I'm just curious what my mistake is!

Comment: Without code, it would be difficult to answer this question.

Comment: @Psychemaster, thanks! I've added code.

Comment: @MontyMarti numbers should start at `{0}`, not `{1}`

Comment: @Nick, thanks! I looked it up and apparently a list is treated as a single item when used as an argument for the .format() method (and I need 10 arguments.)

Comment: @MontyMarti Oh, I didn't even notice that ^^", gj finding the solution though